# Calling a gem method again a second time gets `NameError: uninitialized constant` error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

We have a private gem that I use in several apps. I've made some changes recently. Now calls to my gem only work the first time I call them. The second time I call it again (and thereafter), I get `NameError: uninitialized constant`. Restarting rails console repeats the problem:

```
% bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> Widget::Tool.count
=> 5
irb(main):002:0> Widget::Tool.count
NameError: uninitialized constant Widget::Tool
  from (irb):2
irb(main):003:0> Widget::Tool.count
NameError: uninitialized constant Widget::Tool
  from (irb):3
irb(main):003:0> exit

% bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> Widget::Tool.count
=> 5
irb(main):002:0> Widget::Tool.count
NameError: uninitialized constant Widget::Tool
  from (irb):2
irb(main):003:0> exit
```

This is a hard problem to search for. I'm using bundler and ruby 2.4.5. I've bundled anew. In each case, when I call my gem method again the second time, I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting searching for solutions online, I started backing out my recent changes. In particular, yesterday I made some updates to my gem locally, but wasn't ready to push them to our private repo yet. I also updated Gemfile to point to the local path, instead of our git repo. It was not until today that I tested some of these changes, so they weren't the freshest thing in my mind.

This is what our Gemfile normally looks like:

```
gem 'corp-widget', tag: 'v1.3.0',  corp_git: 'pmpclear/corp-widget-gem', require: 'widget'
```

When I pointed to my local copy of the gem instead, I changed that to:

```
gem 'corp-widget', tag: 'v1.3.0', path: '../corp-widget-gem', require: 'widget'  # DO NOT MERGE!
# TODO: increment to 1.3.1:  gem 'corp-widget', tag: 'v1.3.0',  corp_git: 'pmpclear/corp-widget-gem', require: 'widget'
```

After running `bundle` with this Gemfile, the error in the question started. Through trial and error, I removed `tag: 'v1.3.0'` from the `path` version of the gemfile, and the problem went away:

```
gem 'corp-widget', path: '../corp-widget-gem', require: 'widget'  # DO NOT MERGE!
# TODO: increment to 1.3.1:  gem 'corp-widget', tag: 'v1.3.0',  corp_git: 'pmpclear/corp-widget-gem', require: 'widget'
```

Success:

```
% bundle 
% bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> Widget::Tool.count
=> 5
irb(main):002:0> Widget::Tool.count
=> 5
irb(main):003:0> Widget::Tool.count
=> 5
irb(main):004:0> Widget::Tool.count
=> 5
```

I'm not clear exactly why this works once only. It seems like it would either always work or always fail. I get it that `tag:` doesn't make sense here, so removing it solved my problem.